# OAuth2 with Spring security causing redirect loop

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, oauth-2.0

I have a Java Spring application. I tried to configure OAuth2. So, far I have got the redirect to the SS) page correctly. Afterwards, if I enter the correct username and pwd, it acknowledges my login and then I get a redirect loop.

application.yml

```
authorization-grant-type: authorization_code
redirect-uri: http://localhost:1234/oauth2/callback
```

I have set the authorization uri and token uri correctly.

This is my OAuthSecurityConfiguration.java code

```
@Configuration
public class OAuthSecurityConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.anonymous().disable();
        http.authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/my-gui/**").authenticated()
                .anyRequest().permitAll()
                .and()
                .oauth2Login();
        return http.build();
    }

    @Bean
    WebClient webClient(ClientRegistrationRepository clientRegistrationRepository, OAuth2AuthorizedClientRepository authorizedClientRepository) {
        ServletOAuth2AuthorizedClientExchangeFilterFunction oauth2 = new ServletOAuth2AuthorizedClientExchangeFilterFunction(clientRegistrationRepository, authorizedClientRepository);
        oauth2.setDefaultOAuth2AuthorizedClient(true);
        return WebClient.builder()
                .apply(oauth2.oauth2Configuration())
                .build();
    }
}
```

This is my OAuthController code

```
@Controller
public class OAuthController {

    @Autowired
    private OAuth2AuthorizedClientService authorizedClientService;

    @GetMapping("/oauth2/callback")
    public String handleCallback(HttpServletRequest request, Model model) {
        // Get the OAuth2AuthenticationToken from the request
        OAuth2AuthenticationToken authentication = (OAuth2AuthenticationToken) SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
        // Get the authorized client from the authentication
        OAuth2AuthorizedClient authorizedClient = authorizedClientService.loadAuthorizedClient(authentication.getAuthorizedClientRegistrationId(), authentication.getName());

        // Redirect to the protected page with the access token included as a query parameter
        return "redirect:/my-gui/index.html?access_token=" + authorizedClient.getAccessToken().getTokenValue();
    }
}
```

So, I try to open localhost:1234/my-gui/index.html. This redirects me to an SSO page which is th eexpected behaviour. Here, when I enter the correct username and pwd, I expect it to open localhost:1234/my-gui/index.html which is why I redirect in OAuthController as well. But it just throws me a redirect loop.

I think it is due to the redirect going to a page that needs authentication and causes the loop. Basically, what I want to achieve is have OAuth authentication on localhost:1234/my-gui/index.html and when someone enters the correct pwd, they should see the page.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue and the challenge was that I did not have direct access to register redirect URIs in our provider (Azure). This limited my tests so please consider the following only as a reference.

I ended up requesting to add three redirect URIs and only one solved my issue. It seems that Spring is a little strict in the redirect URI formats. I ended up using redirect URI that matches the default which is:

```
{baseUrl}/login/oauth2/code/{registrationId}
```

Spring also has an option to customize this redirect URI (haven't tested but I would assume the format also matters):

https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/oauth2/login/advanced.html#oauth2login-advanced-redirection-endpoint